# React map - console log works.. but doesn't return value in HTML?

Tags: reactjs

I have nested map array where I want to retrieve the blog entries. `console.log()` will output the description but when I try to return the value of description.. nothing works?

```
import React from 'react';

const Fragrances = (props) => {
const { FragranceArray } = props;
    return (
        <div className="row">
        {

            FragranceArray.map((fragrance, index) => {
                    const dataPosts = fragrance.data.entries;

                    console.log(dataPosts);

                {
                    dataPosts.map((value, index) => {
                        const { category, description, image, name, published, rating } = value;
                        console.log(description);
                        return <h1>{description}</h1>
                    })
                }
            })
        }
        </div>
    )
}
export default Fragrances;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `FragranceArray.map()` callback, you need to return the result of your call to `dataPosts.map()`. This can be done by adding `return` before the line where this mapping is being done (ie `return dataPosts.map(...)`).

Because the mapping returns a collection of items, you will need to wrap those items in an element such as a `<div>` or, alternatively, if you want to preserve the existing structure of your DOM (and avoid adding a "div wrapper") you can use the `<React.Fragmment>` as shown:

```
import React from 'react';

const Fragrances = (props) => {
const { FragranceArray } = props;
    return (
        <div className="row">
        {

            FragranceArray.map((fragrance, index) => {
                    const dataPosts = fragrance.data.entries;

                    console.log(dataPosts);

                // Add return here, and wrap mapped items with React.Fragmment
                return (<React.Fragmment> { 

                    dataPosts.map((value, index) => {
                        const { category, description, 
                                image, name, 
                                published, rating } = value;
                        console.log(description);
                        return <h1>{description}</h1>
                    })
                } </React.Fragmment>)

            })
        }
        </div>
    )
}
export default Fragrances;
```

See the [React documentation more information of `<React.Fragment>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

This expression is doing nothing:

```
{
  dataPosts.map((value, index) => {
      const { category, description, image, name, published, rating } = value;
      console.log(description);
      return <h1>{description}</h1>
  })
}
```

You need to return the result of the children map:

```
import React from 'react';

const Fragrances = (props) => {
const { FragranceArray } = props;
    return (
        <div className="row">
        {

            FragranceArray.map((fragrance, index) => {
                    const dataPosts = fragrance.data.entries;

                    console.log(dataPosts);

                return (
                  <div>
                    {
                      dataPosts.map((value, index) => {
                          const { category, description, image, name, published, rating } = value;
                          console.log(description);
                          return <h1>{description}</h1>
                      })
                    }
                  </div>
                )
            })
        }
        </div>
    )
}
export default Fragrances;
```